# Conditional resolve in ui route before any view is rendered or controller activated

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

After two days of research and failure understanding promises and $q, I 'll describe my problem 
I created service which uses external API

```
.factory('Product', function($http, BASEURL) {
    return {
        get: function(id) {
            return $http.get(BASEURL + '/products/' + id);
        }
    };
})
```

one of states is the product state where i can resolve product with code:

```
.state('app.product', {
    url: '/product/:id',
    resolve: {
        productData: function(Product, $stateParams) {
            return Product.get($stateParams.id)
            }
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
})
```

However I need to redirect user to "product does not exist create new" state if the product of id is not found
and API returns status 404.

Is the "if statement" possible in the resolve block after all reuired data is aquired and before controller renders the state?

here is my failing approach

```
function productData($q, Product, $stateParams, $state) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Product.get($stateParams.id)
    .then(function(result) {
        if (result.status != 404) { //the service responds with full response not the "API response" 
            deferred.resolve(result);
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            $state.go('app.notFound');

        }
    });
}
```

I will need the same error handling with other resources as well

I also tried do it without services by accessing api directly and it kinda worked

```
.state('app.product', {
    url: '/product/:id',
    resolve: {
        productData: checkProductExists
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
})

function checkProductExists($q, $stateParams, $state, $http) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://example.com/api/products/id' + $stateParams.id)
        .success(function(response) {
            if (response.status_code != 404) { //the $http responds with "API response" where i have custom error status codes
                deferred.resolve(response);
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
                $state.go('app.notFound');
            }
        })
        .error(function() {
            deferred.reject();
            $state.go('app.notFound');
        });
    return deferred.promise;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` in your `Product` Factory returns a promise which should allow your `resolve` to access the results of the GET request.

The way you currently have it, `productData` is holding a promise instead of your actual data.

[Refer to the Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> ***then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)*** – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

Try modifying your `resolve` to something like

```
.state('app.product', {
    url: '/product/:id',
    resolve: {
        productData: function(Product, $stateParams) {
            Product.get($stateParams.id).then(function (response) { 
                // successCallback for .then()
                return response.data;
            }, function (error) { 
                // errorCallback for .then() 
                return {};
            });
        }
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl'
})
```

Now you can inject `productData` in your `ProductCtrl` and handle the data however you like, maybe do `$state.go('app.notFound');` if `productData` is empty or something like that

Comment: Khaled thank you for promp response. I did try it before my problem is the timing of the async execution. When I am quering service I got response either 200, 404 and sometimes 500 series when API fails. I simply want assure the product exists (200) and then inject it into controller (which works at the moment) but when I got response 404 redirect user to different state ex. Create new product. What I have at the moment is fireing the controller as my service returns response anyway and product data is empty as API does not return an Item but 404 error. I think I am still missing something in

Comment: Why don't you transition to a different state from your controller if productData is empty as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I think i can't do transition in the controller itself as it was the original problem where view is rendered first with error "productData is undefined" and i thing it should be sorted in resolve of state before we even touch controller and view. What i need is to fully resolve API call first then make decision if i want to proceed with the state i am in or redirect to other one. from the console I have stack like: 
1) Product.get(12322) // service
2) error from controller that productData is undefined
3) and then GET 404 error with response is not containing product data (api response )

Comment: post [here](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/) explains similar issue but even it that i am not able to make my example work as i am using services not resources

Comment: Mind posting a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com) of your controller? are you injecting productData into it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it just by adding return keyword to get the resolved promise. Updated code:

```
.state("cards.newcard", {
            url: "/newcard",
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: "Cards/NewCard",
            controller: "newCardController",
            resolve:
                    {
                        customerProfile: ['customerService', '$rootScope', '$translate', function (customerService, $rootScope, $translate) {
                            return customerService.getCustomerProfile($rootScope.authentication.userName, "", $translate.use()).then(
                            function (response) {
                                return response;
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                return {};
                            });
                            //return customerService.getCustomerProfile($rootScope.authentication.userName, "", $translate.use());

                        }]
                    }
        })
```